# Kafka broker not working after including authorization (ACL)

Tags: authentication, ssl, apache-kafka, authorization, acl

I am new to Kafka and I have been studying about its authorization and authentication methods. Right now, I am testing SSL/TLS authentication, which is working nice (I just need it between external clients and brokers). But when I try to add the authorizer, using ACLs, Kafka just stops working and throws timeout exceptions, like:

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9093 --list --command-config config/admin.properties  Error while executing topic command : Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics [2023-06-25 22:30:32,812] ERROR org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: listTopics (kafka.admin.TopicCommand$)`

This is the security configuration which I have made in *server.properties*:

```
##Authentication 
listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092,SSL://:9093
ssl.keystore.location=[dir]/broker1.ks.p12
ssl.keystore.password=broker1-ks-password
ssl.key.password=broker1-ks-password
ssl.keystore.type=PKCS12
ssl.truststore.location=[dir]/broker1.ts.p12
ssl.truststore.password=broker1-ts-password
ssl.truststore.type=PKCS12
ssl.client.auth=required
ssl.principal.mapping.rules=RULE:^.*[Cc][Nn]=([a-zA-Z0-9.]*).*$/$1/L,DEFAULT


############################ Authorizer ##############################
# Enable ACLAuthorizer
authorizer.class.name=kafka.security.authorizer.AclAuthorizer
super.users=User:admin
```

I have also added a rule into Zookeeper directly, so the broker can work:
`bin/kafka-acls.sh --add --cluster --operation ClusterAction --authorizer-properties zookeeper.connect=127.0.0.1:2181 --allow-principal User:broker1`

But as shown in the beggining, every request to port 9093, finishes with a timeout exception. I know authentication is working, because I have tested it before, but the problem comes with the authorization with ACLs. Can you help me to know what is going wrong? I have tried to find solutions and read all the manuals and guides, without success.